# How can I control the scroll bar of the worksheet in MFC Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-c++, mfc

I'm developing MFC program using Excel Automation in VC++ 6.0.

I want to control the scroll bar so I can place some cell on left top of the worksheet.

I've found that there's a *Application::Goto()* method in VBA which can scroll the worksheet and bring specific cell to top left of the worksheet. 
Well, fortunately in library(Excel.h), I found the same method like following code.

*ADDED:*

```
void _Application::Goto(const VARIANT& Reference, const VARIANT& Scroll)
{
    static BYTE parms[] =
        VTS_VARIANT VTS_VARIANT;
    InvokeHelper(0x1db, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms,
     &Reference, &Scroll);
}
```

But I don't know how to use this method. 
I mean I don't know what the parameters should be. Although I've looked at the MSDN documents, It's only about VBA, not MFC.
[The document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff839232(v=office.14).aspx) says, it can be *Range* object but I really have no idea.

```
m_App.Goto(COleVariant("A10"), gotoScrollTrue);
```

Since I have no idea with using that "*Range* object" into *VARIANT&*, so I just tried like this. However, invalid reference error occurred.

I know it's hard to find information about Excel Automation with MFC, but I have no choice.

I hope there will be someone who can save me.

P.S. I can't switch to another tools like .NET framework. Now the program is working with hardware machine and also it contains many other functions not only moving scroll. And now I'm modifying codes written by my unknown senior. My program is kind of like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/192348/how-to-automate-excel-and-then-know-the-user-closed-it). But MS is only providing these how-to-start like documents about VC++ MFC Excel Automation. I don't know but it feels like that it is an ancient relic. When I google with this, there are very few results which I wanted, and they are almost written about 10 years ago. Anyway, I know I'm clueless, but wish there is someone who knows how to develop Excel automation with VC++.

Comment: You should probably start reading here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 1) First you verify you can write a VBA macro inside of Excel that has the functionality you want.  2) Then you use oleview.exe and browse to the type library of Excel (in excel.exe) and figure out what objects you need. 3) You can #import the library, or skip it and use CComDispatchDriver to make the calls.  On my installation the signature of the function in _Application is         `HRESULT Goto(
                        [in, optional] VARIANT Reference, 
                        [in, optional] VARIANT Scroll, 
                        [in, lcid] long lcid);`

Comment: @RichHolton Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately I think I should stick with this.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson Thank you for posting the comment for me. Your suggestion would be good solution. But because I know nothing about VBA macro, I'm not sure whether I can write a VBA macro. I want to use it but I don't have much time.

Comment: You need to learn C++, MFC, COM (dispatch interface). Chances for you to solve this trivial task within one year: Zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, it takes nothing to create a VBA macro to test your ideas first.  In Excel you go to the View tab and then at the far right open macros and create a macro.  After you figure out what works in VBA, then you translate to another language if necessary.  All Office development should start like that.

If you look at the help for Application.GoTo you'll see that the first argument has to be something that specifies a valid range.  "A10" is not a valid range.  However, "R10C1" should be a valid range, specifying the 10th row and the first column.

Something like this in C++ assuming your m_App is a CComPtr that wraps some sort of IDispatch:

```
_variant_t vResult;
CComDispatchDriver ccdExcel(m_App);
ccdExcel.Invoke2(L"GoTo", &_variant_t(L"R10C1"), &_variant_t(VARIANT_TRUE), &vResult);
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I solved the thing. It was really helpful. Also, thanks to you, now I think I have kind of a little insight into this Office development. Thank you so much.

Comment: Stackoverflow protocol is that when you like an answer you upvote it.  If an answer is the answer to your question, then you mark it as answered.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that.